# Unable to copy a copy protected game save

Tags: ps3, the-evil-within

I have just got The Evil Within for PS3 and I am now stuck at the end with no ammo (go figure). So I had the bright idea to copy the save to my USB and manually change the ammo. The problem is is that it is copy protected and I searched all over the Internet for either a game save (in US version) or a way around this. Does anyone have any other suggestions aside from getting a Playstation Plus account?

Comment: Honestly, the PS+ account is probably going to be the simplest way to go about copying it.  It won't let you edit it, though.  For that, you're going to need to stray into console modding and custom firmware.  Probably wouldn't be worth the effort to do that.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I have been looking all over the internet for a game save because I am literally right at the last chapter and there is not enough ammo to kill the last few enemies so I am always coming up short